# What is the "logic of ejaculations"?

Tags: logic, non-classical-logic

I was looking through a paper on [one valued logic](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2218364?seq=1) and it references something called the "logic of ejaculations", shocked by the name, I tried to find another reference to it in which I found a paper called [A Pyrrhic Defence of Moral Autonomy](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3749544), which references it as well but I cannot find any information on what it could possibly be at a more concrete level. I was wondering if anybody had any information on what this could mean or could find any information on it.

Comment: From the context, it seems to be the logic of expressions like, "How wonderful!" or, "How terrible!" These were important to various emotivist interpretations of moral discourse.

Comment: Yes, in the past it was more common to use "ejaculation" in a non-sexual context including the idea of "verbal ejaculations", see http://dictionary.sensagent.com/Verbal%20ejaculation/en-en/

Comment: That is very interesting. I would like to see some sort of rigorous analysis regarding this. Perhaps these papers will have more to offer than I initially suspected. Thank your for your prompt response. This was incredibly useful and informative.

Comment: True story. When I was in eight grade (long long time ago) we had to go up to the board, spell a word, give its meaning, and use it in a sentence. I ended up with "ejaculate." I did my best to keep a straight face and do the exercise for the non-sexual meaning while all my buddies in class guffawed. I simply can not believe the schools do things like this to kids, in this case me.

Comment: @user4894 all in the name of learning